# how to use finos/perspective https://perspective.finos.org/ in angular 8?

Tags: angular

how to use finos/perspective Datagrid https://perspective.finos.org/ in my angular 8 application.
Input data as JSON, need output as Datagrid.
Any sample code will be helpful.

The GitHub repository is https://github.com/finos/perspective

Answer (score 1):

I've created little demo app [perspective-angular](https://github.com/bocharoviliyav/perspective-angular) . In this example data was uploaded from csv and displayed as datagrid. I think in case of JSON it should be the same.

The main idea is provide support to webcomponents and use node.js api.

I'm install `@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs` as dev dependency, and `@finos/perspective, @finos/perspective-viewer, @finos/perspective-viewer-d3fc, @finos/perspective-viewer-datagrid, @finos/perspective-webpack-plugin.`

In index.html i've added:

```
<script src="webcomponents/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
<script>
    if (!window.customElements) {
        document.write('<!--');
    }
</script>
<script src="webcomponents/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></script>
<!-- ! DO NOT REMOVE THIS COMMENT, WE NEED ITS CLOSING MARKER -->
```

In polyfills.ts :

```
(window as any).global = window;
```

In tsconfig.json:

```
"allowJs": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
```

In angular.json asset:

```
{
    "glob": "**/*.js",
    "input": "node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs",
    "output": "webcomponents/"
}
```

In module where you want use perspective add `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]`

In component add few imports:

```
import perspective, {PerspectiveWorker} from "@finos/perspective";
import "@finos/perspective-viewer";
import "@finos/perspective-viewer-datagrid";
```

And after that you can use `<perspective-viewer>` tag and get acess to it by

```
const viewer: HTMLPerspectiveViewerElement = document.getElementsByTagName("perspective-viewer")[0] as HTMLPerspectiveViewerElement;
```